# How to view space used by the HTTP cache in Chrome devtools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, cache-control, http-caching

Can I view the amount of space used by the built-in HTTP cache, in devtools?

I like to know how much space (while I develop) Chrome is using to cache resources of my app.

Comment: See [Does anyone use chrome://view-http-cache?](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/net-dev/YNct7Nk6bd8/ODeGPq6KAAAJ); [Where has chrome://cache been moved to?](https://superuser.com/q/1316540/); [Why doesn't Chrome respect the DiskCacheSize policy?
Ask Question](https://superuser.com/a/769637/); [ChromeCacheView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html); [A standalone WebApp for viewing chrome://net-export NetLog dump files](https://chromium.googlesource.com/catapult/+/master/netlog_viewer/)

Comment: So basically, not possible in Chrome at all anymore.

Comment: Would not state "not possible". The previous comment was intended as a brief overview of the history and state of the feature.

Comment: See [Chrome DevTools Protocol Viewer - DataEntry -> responseHeaders](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/CacheStorage#type-DataEntry); [Chrome DevTools Protocol Viewer - CachedResponse -> body
string Entry content, base64-encoded.](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/CacheStorage#type-CachedResponse)

Answer (score 1):

In supporting browsers (not Safari or Edge), use this to get a storage estimate:

```
navigator.storage.estimate().then(estimate => console.log(estimate));
```

Output signature varies by browser (Chrome 77.x shown here):

```
{
  quota: 599997077913,
  usage: 265,
  usageDetails: {
    indexedDB: 265
  },
  // .. 
}
```